# Initialize user class in livequery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, parse-platform

can I initialize user class in live query?.. I initialize user class in my index.js and it appears in my [network inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgpSC.jpg). but when I try to query, nothing appears in websocket.

here is my code how i initialize livequery

```
var user = new Parse.Query('_User');
user.equalTo('email', $scope.currentUser.attributes.email);
user.include('money');
userSubscription = user.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use LiveQuery in your parse-server you need to do the following:

1. Make sure that the _User class registered under the LiveQuery classes which located where you initialize your ParseServer (inside the NodeJS index.js file). If you need more classes just add them to the array

```js
    liveQuery: {
      classNames: ['_User']
    }
```

2. Initialize the Parse live query server using the following code:

```js
let httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port);
var parseLiveQueryServer = ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

3. In your JS client you should do the following:

```js
script
let query = new Parse.Query('_User');
let subscription = query.subscribe();

subscription.on('open', () => {
  console.log('open event');
});

subscription.on('update', (object) => {
  console.log('user object updated!');
});
```

You have more events of 'create', 'enter' and more. In order to know how to use it please use [this](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/js/guide/#live-queries) guide.

Comment: I tried to replicate this process, however it didn't work for me.